# Cannot push nodes code to Heroku Git repository

Tags: node.js, heroku

I run:

```
heroku create
```

and

```
git push heroku master
```

Everything Ok, but when I try to view logs, heroku show:

```
npm ERR! missing script: start
```

But, in package.json. I have defined script start.

I tried clone source code on heroku/master, It's not my code, it contains only .gitignore, package.json, README.md ....

I try push code to heroku again, it always show everything up-to-date

Comment: You need to check the current ```package.json``` in heroku/master. Because heroku uses that file to run

Comment: @TienDuong I know, package.json in heroku is not my package.json. That why I cannot start my app, but my question is I cannot push code to heroku. 
I tried git push heroku master, it's success for first time. But I don't know why my code not available in heroku. try to push again, it always show Everything up-to-date

Comment: What branch you are on when you run this command ```git push heroku master```?

Comment: You should know ```heroku``` only push ```master``` branch. So if your are on ```develop``` branch and you run ```git push heroku master``` command, it will still push your ```master``` branch instead of ```develop``` branch

Comment: @TienDuong Oh shit, you right. I'm standing at origin/develop branch. I switch to origin/master and can push it to heroku/master. But in script npm start, I run app by nodemon, heroku show nodemon: not found, although nodemon is a dev dependencies in package.json

Comment: If you share your package.json, I can help you

Comment: @TienDuong package.json content is too long, I cannot paste it into here

Comment: {
  "name": "js-boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "/src/bootstrap.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./src/bootstrap.js --exec babel-node",
  },
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.11"
  }
}

Comment: @TienDuong Above is short package.json, I have removed something unhelpful

Comment: You can post ```package.json``` on https://pastebin.com/ or include it in your question

Comment: Here: https://pastebin.com/embed_js/5AaZrxhj

Comment: Can you share ```dist``` folder structure?

Comment: dev dependencies won't get installed. Make it a production one.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not your code, you need to ensure if you are looking at correct heroku repo. If it is earlier version of your code, see if git push is actually working without errors and pushing to correct repo and branch being used in heroku. Your code should be pushed to master branch (by default) on Heroku.

Comment: When I run heroku create, it created a remote called heroku and this is Heroku's repo. 
I think git push heroku master is right

Comment: Are you pushing all code to master branch? Only master branch will get deployed by default on heroku. Also see logs on heroku if it shows latest pushes or not.

Comment: I am assuming that you are following standard git procedures of adding files to git branch with "git add" , then "git commit" and then "git push". Just "git push" will not make any changes otherwise

Comment: Yes I'm pushing to master. But I'm standing origin/develop, I try to switch to origin/master and push to heroku/master. It's success. Thanks